# SSH login through nautilus fails

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-mint, nautilus

I'm using Linux Mint Maya.  I'm trying to SSH to a remote server.

I can successfully SSH to the server through the command line.  But when I attempt to SSH through Nautilus (using the "Connect to Server" option), it fails with "Access was denied".

I'd like to get more information regarding what's causing this error.  Is there some log that will give me more specific information which might shed some light on why I can login via the command line, but NOT through Nautilus?

Comment: have you checked 'dmesg | tail' ? if you use Ctrl+L to put the nautilus nav bar in text-mode and enter 'ssh://hostname' does nautilus open an SCP session to the server?

Comment: Yeah, dmesg doesn't show information about SSH logins

Comment: ssh login failures do get logged to the servers auth.log

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and had the same issue, actually.  But then I clicked "Remember this password", which prompted me to unlock the keychain, and then it started working.  I don't know what I did or if it will help you....